# Unexpected error when importing txt file

Tags: math-mode, errors

I have the following text, stored as `1.txt`:

```
 qui représentent une même application linéaire. Je me donne, cette fois, une application linéraire de \textit{R⁴} dans \textit{R⁴}, donc une transformation linéaire de \textit{R⁴}. Et voilà la définition de la transformation. Je fixe, d'une part la base canonique, \textit{(e1,e2,...,e4)}, et après une autre base presque quelconque, vous pouvez vérifier que ces quatre vecteurs sont linéairement indépendants, et donc ils forment une base. Et ce que je veux c'est : je vais écrire la matrice de \textit{T} par rapport à la base canonique, ça ne sera pas trop difficile. Et ensuite, j'aimerais utiliser des matrices de passage pour retrouver la matrice de \textit{T} par rapport à la base \textit{B}. Je pourrais aussi juste faire un calcul, mais je souhaite faire ça avec une matrice de passage. D'abord, je trouve \textit{[T]C}, pour ça, ce n'est pas compliqué. Je dois juste appliquer \textit{T} à chaque vecteur de cette base, Je l'applique à \textit{e_1}, donc c'est \textit{T((1,0,0,0))}, j'utilise la formule, et ça, ça me donne \textit{(1,0,0,1)}. Et puis \textit{T} appliquée à \textit{e2}, ça, ça me donne \textit{(1,1,0,0)}. \textit{T} appliquée à \textit{e3}, ça, ça me donne \textit{(0,1,1,0)}. Et enfin, \textit{T} appliquée à \textit{e4}, ça, ça me donne \textit{(0,0,1,1)}. Et maintenant, pour écrire la matrice de \textit{T} par rapport à la base \textit{C},
```

When I try to include it into my latex file, using

```
\input{./texts/1.txt}
```

I get the error:

> Missing $ inserted. ... de cette base, Je l'applique à \textit{e_1}

and

> Extra }, or forgotten $. ... de cette base, Je l'applique à
>   \textit{e_1}

**Anyone know's why ?**

Comment: `_` is a math-only command, to make a subscript, use `\_` to get a literal `_` or perhaps you wanted a subscript in which case `$e_1$` not `\textit{e_1}`

Comment: I suspect all of your `\textit` are intended to mark mathematics and so should be `$...$` this is unrelated to `\input` you would get the same error if the text was in your main file.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle Thank you so much for your comment !

Comment: @DavidCarlisle This solved the problem ! Thank you very much ! Can you add your comment as an answer, such that I can accept it ?